# Jenkins pipeline groovy:how can I get the workspace of another job build

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a job A using groovy code which manages multiple jobs like this:

```
def ret_b = build job:'Job B',parameters: [string(name: 'PROJECT', value: env.project_name)]
```

I need to use the workspace of job B in job A. Since each build of job B would create different workspaces such as workspace@2, I couldn`t hard code it in the pipeline groovy.Is it possible for me to get the workspace of job B?

Answer (score 0):

Use "Shared workspace plugin". This would solve this use case.

More details:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=68747370#content/view/68747370